# What does Judges 19:24 say about the value of females in those days?

Tags: judges

Judges 19:24
Look, here is my virgin daughter, and his concubine. I will bring them out to you now, and you can use them and do to them whatever you wish. But as for this man, don't do such an outrageous thing."

Comment: If you read through and understand the book of Judges, you will realise that what is being described in these later chapters is the state ‘man’ falls to without God, and/or without righteous leaders. When man ‘does what is right in his own eyes’.

Comment: The text reveals the appalling conditions in the city - which were life-threatening. And the text reveals the householder's desire to prevent possible civil war (as reprisal - by the visitor's own people) for what was about to occur. The relative 'value' of female and male is not a feature of what occurred that night

Comment: As with the similar events of [Genesis 19](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2757), Judges 19 simply shows a man's attempts at mitigating sin, homosexual rape being a combination of two sinful inclinations, rather than just one, as rape and homosexuality are, when taken individually. I've also noticed that your last few posts simply consist of copy-pasting scriptural passages without any accompanying explanations; at the *very* least, copy your title within the question body; possibly even expand on it a bit; otherwise, it just looks sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the appalling incident (which I have great trouble even reading!!) only shows what women meant to the people involved at the time.  It illustrates the principle enunciated by Paul in Rom 1:21-29 -

> For although they knew God, they neither glorified Him as God nor gave
> thanks to Him, but they became futile in their thinking and darkened
> in their foolish hearts. Although they claimed to be wise, they became
> fools, and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images of
> mortal man and birds and animals and reptiles.  Therefore God gave
> them over in the desires of their hearts to impurity for the
> dishonoring of their bodies with one another. They exchanged the truth
> of God for a lie, and worshiped and served the creature rather than
> the Creator, who is forever worthy of praise!f Amen.
>
> For this reason God gave them over to dishonorable passions.  ...
> Furthermore, since they did not see fit to acknowledge God, He gave
> them up to a depraved mind, to do what ought not to be done. They have
> become filled with every kind of wickedness, evil, greed, and
> depravity.

The actual situation with women was much better than this as evidenced by OTHER incidents, some of which are in the same book of Judges.  Here are some examples:

- The ancient Israelite patriarchal society did not prevent women from inheriting property.  Num 27:1-11, 36:1-12, Josh 17:3-6.
- Women could be significant leaders, eg., Deborah.  Judges 4.
- Women could be prophets of God; eg, Miriam (Micah 6:4, Ex 15:20, 21), Deborah (Judges 4:4), Huldah (2 Kings 22:14-20), Isaiah’s wife (Isa 8:3), Anna (Luke 2:36), The four daughters of Phillip (Acts 21:8, 9), etc.
- Women could buy and sell property.  Prov 31:16.
- Women could earn independent income and use it at their discretion.  Prov 31:11, 16, 18, 20, Acts 16:12-15, 40.
- Men were required to treat women and wives with great respect – see “Marriage”; in fact, they were to treat wives as Jesus would love them – enough to give His life for them.  Eph 5:25.
- A man could not divorce his wife on whim and marry another without being guilty of adultery.  Matt 19:9 (very different from Roman law), Gen 2:24.
- A man could not deprive his wife of marital privileges.  1 Cor 7:2-4.  (The same was equally required of women.)  See also, “Marriage”.
- Paul had female co-workers in Euodia and Syntyche (Phil 4:2, 3) as well as Junia the apostle (Rom 16:7).  Nympha appears to be the leader of the church that met in her house at Laodicea (Col 4:15).  John also addressed an epistle to a female church leader (2 John 1).
- Women are specifically mentioned as being deacons (using the masculine noun for the female in the Greek!!).  Rom 16:1, 2, 1 Tim 3:11.
- The New Testament church was specifically instructed to care for elderly women who could not support themselves .  1 Tim 5:9-13.

Now, it should be freely admitted that ancient society often failed to live by these standards and often descended into misogyny and many other horrors.  But that is true of almost every sin imaginable - the fact that some failed does NOT make them an example; David was no example in the way he treated Bathsheba at all!!  There are too many other examples like this.

This, in fact, is one of the strengths of the Bible - it portrays its characters a real, flawed humans with all their failings.  Our example is not the failures (although we should learn from these mistakes); but our example is Christ.  1 John 2:6, John 13:34, 35, 15:12, Eph 5:1, 2, Rom 8:29, 12:1, 2, 2 Cor 3:18, Matt 6:12, 14, 15, 18:35, etc.

Comment: Your answer shows how God views women and how far the wicked men in Gibeah had fallen into depravity.  There was no King in Israel and each man did what was right in his own eyes.  They had abandoned God's standards and were as bad as the Canaanites and the Sodomites. +1 for your concluding paragraph.